# Change the remote of all git repositories on a system from http to ssh

Tags: linux, bash, git, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently Github came up with a deprecation notice that the HTTP method of pushing to our repositories is going to expire soon. I've decided to change to the SSH method. On doing that I found that we need to change the remote URL of the repos after setting up keys.

But the change is a tedious process and to do it for all the repositories I have on my local system is quite a lengthy job. Is there some way we can write a Bash script that will go through the directories one by one and then change the remote URL from the HTTP version to the SSH version?

This makes the necessary change from HTTP -> SSH.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo-name
```

The things that we need to change would be the `repo-name` which can be the same as the directory name.

What I thought about was to run a nested for loop on the parent directory that contains all the git repos. This would be something like:

```
for DIR in *; do
    for SUBDIR in DIR; do
        ("git remote set-url..."; cd ..;)
    done
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will identify all subfolders containing a file or folder named `.git`, consider it a repo, and run your command.

**I strongly recommend you make a backup before running it.**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="yourusername"

for DIR in $(find . -type d); do

    if [ -d "$DIR/.git" ] || [ -f "$DIR/.git" ]; then

        # Using ( and ) to create a subshell, so the working dir doesn't
        # change in the main script

        # subshell start
        (
            cd "$DIR"
            REMOTE=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
            # uses quotes to allow spaces in path
            REPO=$(basename "`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`")

            if [[ "$REMOTE" == "https://github.com/"* ]]; then

                echo "HTTPS repo found ($REPO) $DIR"
                git remote set-url origin git@github.com:$USERNAME/$REPO

                # Check if the conversion worked
                REMOTE=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
                if [[ "$REMOTE" == "git@github.com:"* ]]; then
                    echo "Repo \"$REPO\" converted successfully!"
                else
                    echo "Failed to convert repo $REPO from HTTPS to SSH"
                fi

            elif [[ "$REMOTE" == "git@github.com:"* ]]; then
                echo "SSH repo - skip ($REPO) $DIR"
            else
                echo "Not Github - skip ($REPO) $DIR"
            fi
        )
        # subshell end

    fi

done
```

Comment: This is a good starting point. Some suggestions: It would be good to only do this on Github repositories. Ideally it'd iterate over all remotes and not hardcode `origin`, and would skip non-Github and non-http remotes.

Comment: I changed the script with @JohnKugelman 's suggestions for skipping non-http and do this only to github repos. For iterating over all remotes, how would it affect `git config --get remote.origin.url` ?

Comment: Also, I think we would not need `USERNAME`, which could be inferred from the repo remote URL in the `$REMOTE` variable. Need some regex love there, I can get back to that later or someone else can go ahead and improve it.

Comment: There are certainly diminishing returns on making this more and more flexible since it's one-time-use.

Comment: This is also a good use case for `shopt -s globstar` in Bash 4+.

Comment: I'm pretty new... But looks like it requires the folder name and the repo name to be exactly the same for the script to work correctly. I know most times that's the case but sometimes no.

Comment: This will break all your repos origins if there's a space " " in the repos path. You can fix this with by replacing `basename \`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\`` with `basename "\`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\`"`